# Add Report Reference Descriptor to characteristic in CoreBluetooth (BLE)

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to develop an iOs app that emulates a bluetooth mouse. The whole human interface device (hid) stuff is a lot of specifications etc. but I managed my way through so far, at least a little bit I think..
There is an iOs app available, called [BlueTouch](https://getapp.cc/app/1622635358), that according to my researches is using 0x2908 descriptor for characteristics. I am basically trying to reconstruct the used characteristics and descriptors including values for my app, but somehow it is [prohibited by CoreBluetooth to use these descriptors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmutabledescriptor)
Is there any other way to write BLE peripheral applications for iOs than using CoreBluetooth? How was this done in BlueTouch?
Appreciate your help a lot!!

I tried adding the descriptor in every form supported by the API, 16 bit, 32 bit 128 bit.

Edit:
I get the following error when trying to add the service with descriptor 0x2908:

`XPC connection interrupted, resetting`

Then it seems like the bluetooth module resets. I will post a bluetooth log in a minute.

exception from a bluetoothd logfile:

```
Incident Identifier: C1A3C09A-CD57-49D3-9734-46C21319E563
CrashReporter Key:   ce8385164ff073ab00a433a0806726f369422b97
Hardware Model:      iPad7,5
Process:             bluetoothd [88]
Path:                /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
Identifier:          bluetoothd
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.bluetoothd [123]

Date/Time:           2024-03-11 22:36:26.1810 +0100
Launch Time:         2024-03-11 22:34:27.4921 +0100
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.1.1 (21B91)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000008
VM Region Info: 0x8 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476728
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 [384.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [88]

Triggered by Thread:  6

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ec359600 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ec359398 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ec359324 mach_msg_overwrite + 492
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ec35912c mach_msg + 20
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1a9e33044 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1a9e30fa0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1a9e30a04 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1a9e3078c CFRunLoopRun + 60
8   bluetoothd                             0x104736cc0 0x10470c000 + 175296
9   dyld                                   0x1ca6879c4 start + 1572

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3bb08 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3bb08 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  StackLoop
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ec359ef8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3ea78 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1276
2   bluetoothd                             0x1047a46b8 0x10470c000 + 624312
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3c18c _pthread_start + 104
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3bb1c thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:  RxLoop
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ec3664fc kevent + 8
1   bluetoothd                             0x104782af4 0x10470c000 + 486132
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3c18c _pthread_start + 104
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3bb1c thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:  TxLoop
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1ec359ef8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3ea4c _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1232
2   bluetoothd                             0x1047a4288 0x10470c000 + 623240
3   bluetoothd                             0x10488c95c 0x10470c000 + 1575260
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3c18c _pthread_start + 104
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3bb1c thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:   Dispatch queue: com.clemhousa.BluetoothTryout-410
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   bluetoothd                             0x104c31670 0x10470c000 + 5396080
1   bluetoothd                             0x104c314c8 0x10470c000 + 5395656
2   bluetoothd                             0x104bcc02c 0x10470c000 + 4980780
3   bluetoothd                             0x104950340 0x10470c000 + 2376512
4   bluetoothd                             0x104bb4ad4 0x10470c000 + 4885204
5   bluetoothd                             0x104b2bb9c 0x10470c000 + 4324252
6   bluetoothd                             0x10494fe48 0x10470c000 + 2375240
7   libxpc.dylib                           0x20dc91090 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
8   libxpc.dylib                           0x20dc91480 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 952
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b15bf014 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b1577bc4 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 380
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b1566b48 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 336
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b1578790 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 448
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b1566b48 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 336
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b1567738 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 380
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b15684c8 _dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 752
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b1570f4c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 252
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1b157085c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3ba70 _pthread_wqthread + 284
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3bb10 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3bb08 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x20dc3bb08 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000ad29b9040   x1: 0x000000000001f713   x2: 0x000000000001f713   x3: 0x0000000ad2979a00
    x4: 0x0000000000000020   x5: 0x0000000ad2979a00   x6: 0x0000000000000002   x7: 0x0000000000000026
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x00000000000a5250  x10: 0x0000000000056d30  x11: 0x0000000000179f41
   x12: 0x2b4605c62840fc5d  x13: 0x00000001054cca28  x14: 0x0000000053dadcf0  x15: 0x0000000053dadcff
   x16: 0x000000020db955b4  x17: 0x0000000005108452  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000ad29b90a0
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000ad299e140  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000ad2907450  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000105022290  x27: 0x0000000ad29816f0
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016b779700   lr: 0x0000000104c314c8
    sp: 0x000000016b7796f0   pc: 0x0000000104c31670 cpsr: 0x60000000
   far: 0x0000000000000008  esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x105074000 -        0x10507ffff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64  <1e9d839659fb379ca8a6e79667ca38da> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x10470c000 -        0x104fa7fff bluetoothd arm64  <989db0e4f2ec381a9e94699365d978e4> /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
       0x1ec358000 -        0x1ec38efe7 libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <2150c3d02be43a9bb0a3d6509e171790> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1a9dff000 -        0x1aa318fff CoreFoundation arm64  <1ff5bb2494663441bc0c019854f6397d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1ca682000 -        0x1ca6ff793 dyld arm64  <8aa3ebbefedf3ffd90e975e17992a196> /usr/lib/dyld
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  <00000000000000000000000000000000> ???
       0x20dc3a000 -        0x20dc4affb libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <b0158448a3e934fda11225a4fc0ac864> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x20dc36000 -        0x20dc39ffc libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <8507d37233613240a940249d0f24eb23> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
       0x20dc81000 -        0x20dcc0fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <e83efdec0c503e9493bbdd12012a34a3> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
       0x1b155c000 -        0x1b15defff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <c267267838603b39965b5ab54d951b91> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x20db90000 -        0x20db9aff7 libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <fb6f47d1267e378cb2de202c99cbb517> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"bluetoothd","timestamp":"2024-03-11 22:36:27.00 +0100","app_version":"","slice_uuid":"989db0e4-f2ec-381a-9e94-699365d978e4","build_version":"","platform":2,"share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":1,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 17.1.1 (21B91)","roots_installed":0,"incident_id":"C1A3C09A-CD57-49D3-9734-46C21319E563","name":"bluetoothd"}
{
  "uptime" : 130,
  "procRole" : "Unspecified",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "iPad7,5",
  "coalitionID" : 123,
  "osVersion" : {
    "isEmbedded" : true,
    "train" : "iPhone OS 17.1.1",
    "releaseType" : "User",
    "build" : "21B91"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2024-03-11 22:36:26.1810 +0100",
  "codeSigningMonitor" : 0,
  "incident" : "C1A3C09A-CD57-49D3-9734-46C21319E563",
  "pid" : 88,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "roots_installed" : 0,
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "procLaunch" : "2024-03-11 22:34:27.4921 +0100",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 311619870,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 3158824312,
  "procName" : "bluetoothd",
  "procPath" : "\/usr\/sbin\/bluetoothd",
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.bluetoothd",
  "crashReporterKey" : "ce8385164ff073ab00a433a0806726f369422b97",
  "wasUnlockedSinceBoot" : 1,
  "isLocked" : 0,
  "throttleTimeout" : 10,
  "codeSigningID" : "com.apple.bluetoothd",
  "codeSigningTeamID" : "",
  "codeSigningFlags" : 570434305,
  "codeSigningValidationCategory" : 1,
  "codeSigningTrustLevel" : 4294967295,
  "instructionByteStream" : {"beforePC":"oAAAtAgAQPkIBUD5AAE\/1mg6QPmUIgCR9\/\/\/F2AyQPmAAAC0CABA+Q==","atPC":"CAVA+QABP9ZgNkD5YAAAtGA6APkH7waU4AMTqv17Qan0T8KowANf1g=="},
  "vmRegionInfo" : "0x8 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476728\n      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  \n      commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 [384.0G] ---\/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)",
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000008","rawCodes":[1,8],"type":"EXC_BAD_ACCESS","signal":"SIGSEGV","subtype":"KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008"},
  "termination" : {"flags":0,"code":11,"namespace":"SIGNAL","indicator":"Segmentation fault: 11","byProc":"exc handler","byPid":88},
  "vmregioninfo" : "0x8 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476728\n      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT\/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL\n      UNUSED SPACE AT START\n--->  \n      commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 [384.0G] ---\/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)",
  "faultingThread" : 6,
  "threads" : [{"id":944,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":268451845},{"value":21592279046},{"value":8589934592},{"value":90172838379520},{"value":0},{"value":90172838379520},{"value":2},{"value":4294967295},{"value":18446744073709550527},{"value":20995},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":20995},{"value":3072},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":18446744073709551569},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":4294967295},{"value":2},{"value":90172838379520},{"value":0},{"value":90172838379520},{"value":6097412568},{"value":8589934592},{"value":21592279046},{"value":21592279046},{"value":8662052864,"symbolLocation":80,"symbol":"dataSegmentsRanges"}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8257901464},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":6097412416},"sp":{"value":6097412336},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8257902080},"far":{"value":0}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":5632,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":5016,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":4900,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":492,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":4396,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":213060,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":204704,"symbol":"__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1208,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":203268,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":572,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":202636,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":175296,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":22980,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":1572,"imageIndex":4}]},{"id":1440,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6920,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6098546688},{"value":10503},{"value":6098010112},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6098546688},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8820865800},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":1442,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6920,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6099120128},{"value":10759},{"value":6098583552},{"value":6099118976},{"value":5193730},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6099118960},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8820865800},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":1869,"name":"StackLoop","threadState":{"x":[{"value":260},{"value":0},{"value":212224},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":160},{"value":2},{"value":0},{"value":212225},{"value":0},{"value":4378888920},{"value":23089744188674},{"value":5376},{"value":0},{"value":5376},{"value":23089744188674},{"value":305},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":4378888896},{"value":4378888848},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":2},{"value":212224},{"value":212225},{"value":212480},{"value":1000000},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8820877944},"cpsr":{"value":2684354560},"fp":{"value":6103134032},"sp":{"value":6103133888},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8257904376},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":7928,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":19064,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1276,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":624312,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8588,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":6940,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1870,"name":"RxLoop","threadState":{"x":[{"value":4},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6103707280},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1027},{"value":0},{"value":46179488377346},{"value":46179488377346},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":1048576},{"value":9859494864,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_NSConcreteStackBlock"},{"value":9859494864,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_NSConcreteStackBlock"},{"value":363},{"value":8820850104,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"-[__NSStackBlock__ release]"},{"value":0},{"value":46481638680},{"value":5},{"value":1},{"value":4382555832},{"value":4378877952},{"value":4378857472},{"value":32},{"value":27},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4369951476},"cpsr":{"value":1610612736},"fp":{"value":6103707584},"sp":{"value":6103707264},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8257955068},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":58620,"symbol":"kevent","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":486132,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8588,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":6940,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":1912,"name":"TxLoop","threadState":{"x":[{"value":260},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":160},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6104280856},{"value":0},{"value":4378888664},{"value":4398046512130},{"value":1024},{"value":0},{"value":1024},{"value":4398046512130},{"value":305},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":4378888640},{"value":4378909288},{"value":6104281312},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":256},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8820877900},"cpsr":{"value":1610612736},"fp":{"value":6104280976},"sp":{"value":6104280832},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8257904376},"far":{"value":0}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":7928,"symbol":"__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":19020,"symbol":"_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":623240,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":1575260,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":8588,"symbol":"_pthread_start","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":6940,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6}]},{"triggered":true,"id":3609,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":46483083328},{"value":128787},{"value":128787},{"value":46482823680},{"value":32},{"value":46482823680},{"value":2},{"value":38},{"value":0},{"value":676432},{"value":355632},{"value":1548097},{"value":3118186140637658205},{"value":4383885864},{"value":1406852336},{"value":1406852351},{"value":8820184500,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"os_unfair_lock_unlock$VARIANT$mp"},{"value":84968530},{"value":0},{"value":46483083424},{"value":0},{"value":46482972992},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":46482355280},{"value":0},{"value":4378993296},{"value":46482855664},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4374861000},"cpsr":{"value":1610612736},"fp":{"value":6097966848},"sp":{"value":6097966832},"esr":{"value":2449473542,"description":"(Data Abort) byte read Translation fault"},"pc":{"value":4374861424,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":8}},"queue":"com.clemhousa.BluetoothTryout-410","frames":[{"imageOffset":5396080,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5395656,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4980780,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2376512,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4885204,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4324252,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":2375240,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":65680,"symbol":"_xpc_connection_call_event_handler","symbolLocation":68,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":66688,"symbol":"_xpc_connection_mach_event","symbolLocation":952,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":405524,"symbol":"_dispatch_client_callout4","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":113604,"symbol":"_dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":380,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":43848,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":336,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":116624,"symbol":"_dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":448,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":43848,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":336,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":46904,"symbol":"_dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":380,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":50376,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":752,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":85836,"symbol":"_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh","symbolLocation":252,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":84060,"symbol":"_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":404,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":6768,"symbol":"_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":6928,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":6}]},{"id":5215,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6920,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6100267008},{"value":89363},{"value":6099730432},{"value":0},{"value":409603},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6100267008},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8820865800},"far":{"value":0}}},{"id":5632,"frames":[{"imageOffset":6920,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":6}],"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6099693568},{"value":111135},{"value":6099156992},{"value":0},{"value":409604},{"value":18446744073709551615},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":0},"cpsr":{"value":0},"fp":{"value":0},"sp":{"value":6099693568},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8820865800},"far":{"value":0}}}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4379328512,
    "size" : 49152,
    "uuid" : "1e9d8396-59fb-379c-a8a6-e79667ca38da",
    "path" : "\/private\/preboot\/Cryptexes\/OS\/usr\/lib\/libobjc-trampolines.dylib",
    "name" : "libobjc-trampolines.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4369465344,
    "size" : 9027584,
    "uuid" : "989db0e4-f2ec-381a-9e94-699365d978e4",
    "path" : "\/usr\/sbin\/bluetoothd",
    "name" : "bluetoothd"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8257896448,
    "size" : 225256,
    "uuid" : "2150c3d0-2be4-3a9b-b0a3-d6509e171790",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 7144992768,
    "size" : 5349376,
    "uuid" : "1ff5bb24-9466-3441-bc0c-019854f6397d",
    "path" : "\/System\/Library\/Frameworks\/CoreFoundation.framework\/CoreFoundation",
    "name" : "CoreFoundation"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 7690788864,
    "size" : 513940,
    "uuid" : "8aa3ebbe-fedf-3ffd-90e9-75e17992a196",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "size" : 0,
    "source" : "A",
    "base" : 0,
    "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8820858880,
    "size" : 69628,
    "uuid" : "b0158448-a3e9-34fd-a112-25a4fc0ac864",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8820842496,
    "size" : 16381,
    "uuid" : "8507d372-3361-3240-a940-249d0f24eb23",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_blocks.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_blocks.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8821149696,
    "size" : 262144,
    "uuid" : "e83efdec-0c50-3e94-93bb-dd12012a34a3",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libxpc.dylib",
    "name" : "libxpc.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 7270154240,
    "size" : 536576,
    "uuid" : "c2672678-3860-3b39-965b-5ab54d951b91",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libdispatch.dylib",
    "name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 8820162560,
    "size" : 45048,
    "uuid" : "fb6f47d1-267e-378c-b2de-202c99cbb517",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_platform.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_platform.dylib"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7017185280,
  "size" : 3274473472,
  "uuid" : "846d8339-18a7-3844-a274-583aa5cd6212"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=879.1M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=879.1M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=44.6M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=44.6M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nDispatch continuations            2048K        1 \nFoundation                          16K        1 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                            36.4M       24 \nMALLOC guard page                  128K        8 \nSMOOTH                               24        2 \nSQLite page cache                  384K        3 \nSTACK GUARD                        144K        9 \nStack                             5360K        9 \n__CTF                               824        1 \n__DATA                            10.4M      561 \n__DATA_CONST                      51.3M      577 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      5566K      533 \n__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 \n__INFO_FILTER                         8        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       371.8M        3 \n__OBJC_RO                         84.8M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         2658K        1 \n__TEXT                           507.4M      581 \ndyld private memory                272K        2 \nmapped file                       40.2M       11 \nshared memory                       80K        4 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.1G     2336 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.clemhousa.BluetoothTryout-410"
  }
},
  "logWritingSignature" : "29834c139744683b4139bf8432c94ac0b1758738",
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "63f9578e238e7b23a1f3030a",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000005
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "6425c75e4327780c10cc4252",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_HOME_AUTOMATION_INTENT_SELECTION_CACHE" : "642600a457e7664b1698eb32"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000004
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [
    {
      "treatmentId" : "51e1e7b0-9e1f-4bff-b73b-1e886c06aa1b",
      "experimentId" : "65eb82c95e31b60d077e7f9b",
      "deploymentId" : 400000002
    },
    {
      "treatmentId" : "a4d11e8a-ba67-4719-8b0b-f16216534b45",
      "experimentId" : "65eb8151a10809080a087b0c",
      "deploymentId" : 400000003
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add the error message you are getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.